# Accessing Microsoft Graph API : Resource app ID: 00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000

Tags: azure, active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I've been using the following code sample to test access to the Microsoft Graph API from a Java application:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-au/resources/samples/active-directory-java-webapp-openidconnect/

In my Azure portal I've created a Registered app under Azure Active Directory.  I've gone into `API Access > Required Permissions` and added `Microsoft Graph` and checked all the Application Permissions and Delegated Permissions.

When I try to call the sample application's 'Show users in the tenant' function, I get the following error message from the Microsoft Login process:

> AADSTS65005: Invalid resource. The client has requested access to a resource which is not listed in the requested permissions in the client's application registration. Client app ID: 1b350134-84b1-4ca1-a181-03e3699996a1. Resource value from request: https://graph.windows.net. Resource app ID: 00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000. List of valid resources from app registration: 00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000.

Can anyone suggest how to proceed from here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have given permissions to wrong API.

The sample is intended to work with Azure AD Graph API. It's called Windows Azure Active Directory in the API selection.

Comment: @Black: 00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000 is the Azure Active Directory Graph API. That is not identical to the Microsoft Graph, which you have given permissions to.

Comment: thank you @juunas !  That works.  Can you tell me why, with the correct permissions now specified in the portal, the application still redirects to a Microsoft page (under https://login.microsoftonline.com) asking me to grant the specified application permissions to resources belonging to users in my organization?  Isn't that what I did in the portal?

Comment: When you specify the permissions, you are saying "This application requires these permissions on these APIs". Granting those permissions is a separate action. You can do it by pressing the Grant permissions button in the portal too. Otherwise user consent will be asked.